# How to make a clickable image that carries a variable to another page in php?

Tags: php, html, get, request

My question is pretty simple. I tried doing some research into this but I never got it working with images.

I want to have a clickable image so when a user clicks on that image, it carries over some type of variable (ID) to another php page, so I can know which image that user clicked on and give the result.

My current code is this:

```
    echo '<a href="viewer.php"><img  src=' . $covers->src . 'height="300" width="190" value=' . $test . ' name="view" /></a>';
```

I tried doing this on my second php page:

```
$var_value = $_GET['view];
echo $var_value;
```

but I get undefined error on line 1.

Comment: There is a quote missing on line 1 of that last code part.

Comment: what type of variable you want to carry over? a string? an array? a complex object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to fetch a parameter called `view` with `$_GET`. Simply add a parameter to your link called `view` and then its value.

```
echo '<a href="viewer.php?view=theValueIWantToBringAlong"><img  src="' . $covers->src . '" height="300" width="190" name="view" /></a>';
```

In this example, using

```
echo $_GET['view'];
```

when at viewer.php will print "`theValueIWantToBringAlong`".

If your value is is stored in a variable, then do like this:

```
$myValue = 'theValueIWantToBringAlong';
echo '<a href="viewer.php?view='.$myValue.'"><img  src="' . $covers->src . '" height="300" width="190" name="view" /></a>';
```

Comment: Very helpful, Thanks @entiendoNull

Answer (score 0):

You want to put the values in the `href` of the `<a>` tag, not within the attributes of the `<img>`.

Change:

```
echo '<a href="viewer.php"><img  src=' . $covers->src . 'height="300" width="190" value=' . $test . ' name="view" /></a>';
```

to:

`echo '<a href="viewer.php?view=' . $test . '"><img  src=' . $covers->src . 'height="300" width="190"/></a>`';

An `<a>` isn't like a `<form>`. It can't pass values from elements inside of it to the link. The only way to do this with an `<a`> is to put the values within the `href`. The key/value pairs after the `?` are then accessible in `$_GET`.

`value` and `name` are not valid attributes for img, see [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
echo '<a href="viewer.php?view="' . $test . '">';
echo '<img  src="' . $covers->src . '" height="300" width="190"/></a>';
```

Note also that you did not provide quotes around the `src` value of the image and 
that you had no space before `height`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href=viewer.php?view={$test}><img src='{$covers->src}' height=300 width=190 name=view /></a>";
```

Comment: I've removed all the optional quotes from the HTML, and changed to using double quotes around the entire thing so that it'll auto-expand the PHP variables. I left the quotes around src because you may need them depending on your values of `$covers->src`.